# Why these read-only operations cause the error "attempt to write in a read only database"

Tags: sqlite

I open the database

```
 sqlite3 /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite
```

in the database, I try to list every table and then select the content of a table

```
.tables
```

> Error: attempt to write a readonly database

```
select * from t_I_dont_know_if_this_table_exists;
```

> Parse error: attempt to write a readonly database

This database is very very probably read only but these 2 operations shouldn't change the data. I don't understand why I get this message.

Comment: How have you set the database to be readonly? I've set the file to be readonly (0444) and the commands run fine. v3.40.0

Comment: @Schwern I have'nt set the database myself. I've installed the nix package manager. The database was installed during this installation

Comment: Try `ls -l /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite` and see if it's read only.

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2404352 Dec 16 22:04 /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite I'm connecting as user different from root not in the group root. So I can only read it.  But my operations are nonetheless readonly

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell sqlite3 it shouldn't touch the database:

```
   $ sqlite3 "file:/nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite?immutable=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the CLI does not have write permission to wherever it is trying to write command line history file `.sqlite_history`. Try setting the environment variable `SQLITE_HISTORY` (incuding file name) to a writeable location.